# Build list programatically in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, dynamic, gradient

Any ideas how to create this list dinamically using some math functions or something? It looks really ugly like this. There isn't an exact pattern for how the colors are so I'm not sure how to do this. Help would be much appreciated.

```
val colorGradient = listOf(
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.95f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.95f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.95f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.9f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.9f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.9f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.85f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.85f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.85f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.85f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.55f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.4f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.2f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
    backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.05f),
    Color.Transparent,
    Color.Transparent
)
```

Comment: If there isn't a pattern you most likely can't. However, a gradient itself is a pattern, angle, spread, and whatnot. So you need to know exactly what gradient you're applying.

Comment: I'm applying a vertical gradient on a brush with compose and I just couldn't make it look how I want with less colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also start with a list of count of each gradient step:

```
val colorGradient = listOf(1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2)
  .flatMapIndexed { index, count -> List(count) { (1 - (index * 5) / 100.0).toFloat() } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that there is no real pattern, I would do it like this to make it more compact:

```
val gradients = listOf(1.0f, 0.95f, 0.95f, 0.95f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.6f, 0.55f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
val colorGradient = gradients.map { backgroundColor.copy(alpha = it) }
```

Comment: I makes sense, this looks much better so thank you.